# multiprocessing is not doing multi process

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

In python I have created 4 process to open multi tabs simultaneously but tabs are opened in sequence but not parrellelly.

code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def func1(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get('http://www.rediff.com')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get('http://yatra.com')
    driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    driver.get('http://makemytrip.com')

def func2(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')
    driver.refresh()


def func3(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
    driver.refresh()




if __name__=='__main__':
     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver.get('https://www.google.com')
     p1 = Process(target = func1(driver))
     p1.start()
     p2 = Process(target = func2(driver))
     p2.start()
     p3= Process(target=func3(driver))
     p3.start()
```

What is the reason? How to open 3 tabs simultaneously and assign different  task to different tabs?

Comment: You need to provide a function to `Process`. As it is, you are providing the result which is probably `None`.

Comment: @FlorentB. i have provided argument func1, func2 and func3 and are not result. please provide suggestion how to amend this code for opening multi tab concurrenlty

Comment: you are providing the result since `func1(driver)` will first execute the function and then assign the result to `target`. Anyway, it's not possible to interact with different windows simultaneously with a single instance of the driver.